# How can I convert the following data into LOOP

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to convert the following into loop but whatever I tried all in vain 
I want someone help me to convert this type of data into loop.

```
ArrayList<String> parentList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList> childListHolder = new ArrayList<>();

        parentList.add("Parent1");
        parentList.add("Parent2");
        parentList.add("Parent3");

        ArrayList<String> childNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        childNameList.add("Child1");
        childNameList.add("Child2");
        childNameList.add("Child3");

        childListHolder.add(childNameList);

        childNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        childNameList.add("Child4");
        childNameList.add("Child5");
        childNameList.add("Child6");

        childListHolder.add(childNameList);

        childNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        childNameList.add("Child7");
        childNameList.add("Child8");
        childNameList.add("Child9");

        childListHolder.add(childNameList);
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

No need for loop(s) here, also don't use `ArrayList` as a raw-type and prefer the `List` interface. Use `Arrays.asList(T...)` to generate your `List`(s). Like,

```
List<List<String>> childListHolder = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> parentList = Arrays.asList("Fruits & Vegetables", 
        "Beverages & Health", "Home & Kitchen");
childListHolder.add(Arrays.asList("Apple", "Mango", "Banana"));
childListHolder.add(Arrays.asList("Red bull", "Maa", "Horlicks"));
childListHolder.add(Arrays.asList("Knife", "Vessels", "Spoons"));
```

Comment: I want to fetch data from API I am getting perfect result  in log but issue is with the loop

Comment: So I need a loop

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of your code with loops is this:

```
ArrayList<String> parentList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList> childListHolder = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    parentList.add("Parent" + i);

    ArrayList<String> childNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
        childNameList.add("Child" + (3 * (i - 1) + j));
    }
    childListHolder.add(childNameList);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way we can do this with nested loop 
I don't want multiple loops

Comment: This is **nested** loops. The first loop fills `parentList`. The next loop uses nested loops.

Comment: This returns duplicate child for each parent

Comment: This is the result for `childListHolder`: `[[Child1, Child2, Child3], [Child4, Child5, Child6], [Child7, Child8, Child9]]`. Where are the duplicates?

Comment: Let me get to the point 
I am getting categories and subcategories and make an expandable layout from this, and I am not able to set subcategories

Comment: That's why I am asking this question

Comment: if you need to see that kindly take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55329498/fetch-categories-and-sub-categories-from-web-server

Comment: The code you posted in your question creates a list of lists. This is exactly the same as what my code does but in a compact way using loops. This is what you ask in your question: *I am trying to convert the following into loop*. If this is not what you want then you must post a new question were you can clarify,

Comment: I am just trying to accomplish this! https://imgur.com/Ugj4BIO
Is there any better way to do this let me know it will be a great help

Comment: Look there is tab name Personal Care  this is my parent or category and the data within that are childs or sub-categories

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426160/android-retrofit2-how-can-i-create-expandable-recycler-view-for-categories-and