# Android Retrofit2: How can I create expandable recycler view for categories and subcategories?

Tags: android, retrofit, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am trying to archive this functionality for my grocery app https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX3tS.jpg
But I am failed to do so!

I am showing you what I am able to archive. if you have any **Better Solution** let me know.

Here is my Json code from which I am fetching my data from web server right now its localhost

```
{"cats":
[{"sub_cats": 
 [{
 "sub_id":"1",
 "sub_title":"Charger",
 "sub_img":"http:\/\/localhost\/adminPohanch\/public\/img\/img23.jpg"
 },
 {
  "sub_id":"2",
  "sub_title":"Dummy",
  "sub_img":"https:\/\/encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com\/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTrRRV2S-HAzHVIfS0EtgfIeWnej05TRN1PqWQCLW44h3NqM9UOtQ"
 }
],
"id":"52",
"title":"Electric Equipments",
"img":""}],
"message":"Categories Loaded","success":1}
```

Here is the retofit's API abstract class's method

```
@GET("cats.php")
    Call<Categories> getCategories();
```

My Categories Model Class is this

```
public class Categories {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("img")
    @Expose
    private String img;
    @SerializedName("sub_id")
    @Expose
    private String sub_id;
    @SerializedName("sub_title")
    @Expose
    private String sub_title;
    @SerializedName("sub_img")
    @Expose
    private String sub_img;

    @SerializedName("cats")
    @Expose
    private List<Categories> cats = null;

    @SerializedName("sub_cats")
    @Expose
    private List<Categories> sub_cats = null;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Integer success;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(String img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getSub_id() {
        return sub_id;
    }

    public void setSub_id(String sub_id) {
        this.sub_id = sub_id;
    }

    public String getSub_title() {
        return sub_title;
    }

    public void setSub_title(String sub_title) {
        this.sub_title = sub_title;
    }

    public String getSub_img() {
        return sub_img;
    }

    public void setSub_img(String sub_img) {
        this.sub_img = sub_img;
    }

    public List<Categories> getCats() {
        return cats;
    }

    public void setCats(List<Categories> cats) {
        this.cats = cats;
    }

    public List<Categories> getSub_cats() {
        return sub_cats;
    }

    public void setSub_cats(List<Categories> sub_cats) {
        this.sub_cats = sub_cats;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Integer getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Integer success) {
        this.success = success;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my **Activity**
from which I am getting result/data and initializing to my Adapter

```
Call<Categories> callCats = RetrofitBuilder.getInstance().getApi().getCategories();
        callCats.enqueue(new Callback<Categories>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Categories> call, Response<Categories> response) {
                Categories cats = response.body();
                Log.d("cats", "onResponse: " + cats);
                if (cats != null){
                    List<Categories> catsList = cats.getCats();

                    Log.d("Categories", "onResponse: " + catsList.size());
                    Log.d("Categories", "onResponse: " + cats.getCats().toString());

                    for(int i = 0; i < catsList.size(); i++){

                        Categories categoriesData = new Categories();
                        String id = catsList.get(i).getId();
                        String title = catsList.get(i).getTitle();
                        String img = catsList.get(i).getImg();

                        categoriesData.setId(id);
                        categoriesData.setTitle(title);
                        categoriesData.setImg(img);

                        getCatItems.add(categoriesData);

                        List<Categories> sub = catsList.get(i).getSub_cats();
                        Toast.makeText(BuyerDashboard.this, ""+sub.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        for (int j = 0; j < sub.size(); j++){

                            Categories categories = new Categories();
                            categories.setId(sub.get(i).getSub_id());
                            categories.setSub_title(sub.get(i).getSub_title());
                            categories.setSub_img(sub.get(i).getSub_img());
                            getSubItems.add(categories);

                        }
                    }

                    ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter expandableCategoryRecyclerViewAdapter =
                            new ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getCatItems, getSubItems);
                    expanderRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                    expanderRecyclerView.setAdapter(expandableCategoryRecyclerViewAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Categories> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(BuyerDashboard.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

**ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter **

```
public class ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<Categories> nameList ;
    List<Integer> counter = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Categories> itemNameList;
    Context context;

    public ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,
                                         List<Categories> nameList,
                                         List<Categories> itemNameList ) {
        this.nameList = nameList;
        this.itemNameList = itemNameList;
        this.context = context;

        Log.d("namelist", nameList.toString());

        for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++) {
            counter.add(0);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cat_items, viewGroup, false);

        ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder vh = new ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Categories categories = nameList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(categories.getTitle());
        InnerRecyclerViewAdapter itemInnerRecyclerView = new InnerRecyclerViewAdapter(itemNameList, context);
        holder.cardRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 2));

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (counter.get(position) % 2 == 0) {
                    holder.cardRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    holder.cardRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                counter.set(position, counter.get(position) + 1);
            }
        });
        holder.cardRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemInnerRecyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return nameList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        ImageButton dropBtn;
        RecyclerView cardRecyclerView;
        CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryTitle);
            dropBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryExpandBtn);
            cardRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.innerRecyclerView);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

        }
    }
}
```

**InnerRecyclerViewAdapter** For Childs/(sub-categories)

```
public class InnerRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InnerRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<Categories> nameList;
    Context context;
    public InnerRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Categories> nameList, Context context) {

        this.nameList = nameList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.sub_cat_items, parent, false);


        InnerRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder vh = new InnerRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Categories subCategories = nameList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(subCategories.getTitle());
        holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(context, ProductsActivity.class);
                Categories subCategories = nameList.get(position);
                i.putExtra("sub_cat_id", subCategories.getId());
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return nameList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView);
        }
    }
}
```

Right now I am not displaying anything for Images I am focusing on Title of categories(parents) and sub-categories (child)

Here is my **sub_cat_items** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHolder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sub_cat_img"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/pohanch" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Fresh Fruits"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the last here is my **cat_items** File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHolder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/categoryTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Fruits &amp; Vegetables"
                        android:textColor="@color/basiccolor"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/categoryExpandBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:background="#FFF"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_downward_black_24dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/innerRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutHolder"
                android:background="#f6f6f6"
                android:visibility="gone">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I am **successful** in displaying **Categories (parents)** to the output but having issues with **subcategories(children)**

Here is my output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdKGH.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this example code for customized  `expandableview`.
https://github.com/developernadeem/ShopGrocery

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView is for list not for ExpandableListView maybe you want to check this tutorial: https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Or maybe want to check this library: https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

Of course you can use RecyclerView but you have to change the layout doing your own calculations, and making the listener to make the expandable and not expandable

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit returns object
Configure classes this way

```
public class Category{
List<Cats> cats;
private String message;
private int success;
}



Public class Cats{
List<SubCats> sub_cats;
private String id;
private String title;
private String img;
}



public class SubCats{
private String sub_id;
private String sub_title;
private String sub_img;
}
```

Now

```
@GET("cats.php")
Call<Category> getCategories();
```

Yo need to configure JSON as well, Remove red marked in the image. It seems unnecessary.
Reconfigure the PHP as well[image: Need to format your response object]